# Why do I need to reload my page to get data from a subjectSubscription in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm running into a problem in my angular app.

I want to get data from firebase in my component "statsview" using ngOnInit() and a subscription to a subject.

Here is the subscription to the subject.

```js
      export class StatsviewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      
      stats : Stats;
      statsSubscription : Subscription;  
      
      constructor(private hbService:HbService) { }
      
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.statsSubscription = this.hbService.statsSubject.subscribe(
          (stats:Stats) => {            
              this.stats= stats;           
          }
        );
        this.hbService.statsSubject.next(this.stats);
      }
```

Here is what I want to display.

```html
      
      <h1>nc : {{ stats.nc }}</h1>
      <h1>Réponse au 1er Message : {{ stats.firstMess }}</h1>
      <h1>Date : {{ stats.firstDate }}</h1>
      <h1>FC : {{ stats.fc }} </h1>
```

When the application loads the page the value "**stats**" from the observable gets the right data and it works BUT when I go on an other component and get back to my "statsview" the value "stats" is **undefined** and nothing appears in the view. To get my statsview working I need to reload the page (F5)...

I don't understand why it does not work correctly when I navigate in my application and go back to my statview without refreshing the page.

My subject declaration is in hbService and I put the function getStats() in the constructor.

Here is the function getStats() in hbService.

```js
getStats(){
    firebase.database().ref('/stats/').on('value', (data: DataSnapshot) => {
      this.stats = data.val() ? data.val() : this.stats;
      this.statsSubject.next(this.stats); 
    });
```

Here is the function called in the constructor of hbService and the declaration of the subject.

```js
export class HbService {

  stats : Stats;
  statsSubject = new Subject<Stats>();
   
  constructor(private router: Router) { this.getHbs(); this.getStats(); }
```

I wanna know why when I navigate in other component and get back to my component statsview my observable does not get data from the subject subscription.

Comment: why are you calling `next` in the components `ngOnInit`? Pretty sure that is undefined in that moment

Comment: Thank you very much it works now ! I called the function next() from the hbService and at that moment stats is not undefined. So, to make sure I understood. It works when i called next from hbService because the promise got time to get data back into stats right ?

Comment: I can't be exactly sure what was the cause of the issue. I just saw you were calling `next` from both, the component and the service. Usually the service will push first with data, because services are instanciated during app start, before components. It looked like the component was then overwriting it, because it called `next` immediatly. The code inside `subscribe` will always be called after `this.hbService.statsSubject.next(this.stats);` because it is async.

Comment: yes so it worked because before `this.stats` was the variable from `susbribe` so it was empty when calling `next` (because of async) and using the function written in `hbService` `emitStats(){
    this.statsSubject.next(this.stats);  
   }` is better because `this.stats`comes from hbService so it is not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [BehaviourSubject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject):

`statsSubject = new BehaviourSubject<Stats>(undefined);`

It can hold a `currentValue` and will emit it when subscribed to , while a regular `Subject` will only emit in the same moment as it is being pushed to.